# How can I use simd in MIPS?

Tags: gcc, simd, mips32

I have installed mipsel-linux-gcc in the pictrue

[image]
Now I have a file simd.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"simdType.h"
int main()
{

v4i32 m,t;
v4f32 a,b,c,s;
a=b+c;
t=b<c;
s = __builtin_shuffle(b,c,m);
return 0;
}
```

then I run this command:

```
mipsel-linux-gcc -S simd.c -mfp64 -Wa,-mmsa -mhard-float
```

then I get *simd.s*, but it's not in *simd*  format.
Who can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try enabling optimization?  (`-O3`)

Comment: Also, I'd suggest not use the `root` account on your Ubuntu machine when you don't need to write to system directories.

Comment: What's `simdType.h`?  It doesn't come with MIPSel gcc5.4 on Godbolt.  https://godbolt.org/g/96Dfdr

Comment: Try reading https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-SIMD-Architecture-_0028MSA_0029-Support.html.  It suggests including `<msa.h>` and compiling with `-mmsa -mhard-float -mfp64 -mnan=2008`.  That doesn't seem to work on Godbolt, so IDK.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks very much! I define 'v4i32' in the 'simdType.h'. It seems that all the options in '-Wa don't' work

Comment: `-Wa` passes options to the assembler.  You need `-mmsa` to enable it for the compiler to emit those instructions.  Maybe some old versions of the assembler also need `-Wa,-mmsa` to enable support for assembling the compiler's output, but if it works for you without it then don't use it.

Comment: Offical suggests including <msa.h> and compiling with -mmsa -mhard-float -mfp64 -mnan=2008. '-mmsa' can only be used in '-Wa' . But I found all the  options in '-Wa' don't work, like '-Wa,-mips16,-micromips'. So I think '-Wa' result in my problem.